# What is the optimal way to write function-based views in Django?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-views

What is the recommended way to write views (as functions) in Django?

I am asking in terms of readability, etc.
For example: define the template first, then do the translations, then define models and lastly define context.

Here is some example code:

```
def index(request): # Landing page, translated to the browser's language (default is english)
    template = loader.get_template("koncerti/index.html")

    # Translators: This is the text on the homepage buttons
    concerts = gettext("Koncerti")
    band = gettext("Band")
    # Translators: This is the option in the language-switch box
    foreignLanguage = gettext("eng")

    koncertiUrl = '/koncerti/international' # The URL slug leading to 'koncerti' page
    bandUrl = '/band/international' # The URL slug leading to 'band' page
    translationMode = '' # The URL slug that is leading to slovenian translation mode

    context = {
        'Concerts' : concerts,
        'Band' : band,
        'foreignLanguage' : foreignLanguage,
        'koncertiUrl' : koncertiUrl,
        'bandUrl' : bandUrl,
        'translationMode' : translationMode
    }

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: You are doing too much in your view. Normally translations and URL resolution are done in the template. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing too much in the view. A view is supposed to make the proper querysets, and make changes to the database. It's main task is thus to decide *what* to render, and *what* to update. *Not* how to update it.

Deciding about translations, url resolution, etc. is normally a task of the *template*. The template has template tags for that such as [**`{% trans … %}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#trans-template-tag) and [**`{% url … %}`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url).

Using the `{% url … %}` over raw URLs you construct yourself is strongly advisable. It makes the odds of making a mistake smaller, and furthermore it is clear to what view you are referring.

You furthermore might want to use [**`render(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#render). This function combines looking for a template, rendering that template with the template render engine, and returning a HTTP response.

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    return render(request, 'koncerti/index.html', {})
```

In the template, you can then render this with:

```
{% load i18n %}
<a href="{% url 'view-name' %}">{% trans 'Koncerti' %}</a>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. I know I am replying 3 months late, but when you answered I couldn't really comprehend your answer. Now, I can understand more clearly what you meant. Cheers!